# Android photo app with screen flip

Tags: android, photography, touchscreen

The bottom half of my phone's touchscreen has stopped working. Until I get it fixed (after Covid-19 lockdown) I'm able to work with it...as most applications will rotate 180° when I flip the phone.

Alas the default photo app does not rotate, and I can't take any photos. Can anyone recommend an alternative photo app which will flip, and allow me to take photos? Can this app also replace the default photo app, to allow it to open with a gesture, as usual?